# What is the issue with displaying data in this code?

Tags: python

```
class s(object):
    def vrod(self):
        self.name=(input("enter name:"))
        self.stno=int(input("enter stno:"))
        self.score=int(input("enter score:"))

    def dis(self):
        j=0
        while j<3:
            print("enter name:",self.name,"enter stno:",self.stno,"enter score:",self.score)
            j+=1


y=[]
j=0
st=s()

while j<3:
    st.vrod()
    y.append(st)
    j+=1

st.dis()
```

I want to display information that I enter, but I cannot. You suppose that I run that and enter name, student number and score. Then, I only receive information from the third person which is tripled. Why and how can I eliminate problem?
Thanks

Comment: you only create one instance of `s` and then call it's `.vrod()` method 3 times (of the same object) you need to create three different objects instead to end up with 3 different objects.

Comment: Kevin, I used list. What do you mean?

Comment: Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, Do you mean that I should use three of lists. I used y=[]. Do you mean that I should add other two one like x=[] and c=[]?

Comment: Both commenters offer valuable hints. In case you want to store multiple "data sets" inside an instance of class s, you need to have the `vrod` method to target lists where each call finds "new" slots that will be appended (as an example). In case the class instance shall only keep one "data set", then you need a different container to be filled inside the while loop, here also a list might come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that need to be addressed:

1. The `st` object is created once and then used multiple times in the while loop. This calls the same method of the same object multiple times, so the previous information is lost.
2. The `st` object is being appended to the array multiple times. Because it is the same object being appended, if the object is updated, all if the elements in the array are updated with the same information.
3. In the `dis` method, it appears what you want to do is iterate over the array and show all of the inputs received. The function is a member of an object, however, and the object has no knowledge of the other instantiated objects. What `dis` should do instead is only print the data related to a single object and then have external code call that method on each object.
4. Your code never actually uses the array that it is trying to use to store previous information. This shows that you do not have a good understanding of how arrays, objects, and scope works. I would take a look at some resources for learning more about Object Oriented Programming (OOP) and Python. For example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Here is some updated code that will do what you are looking for:

```
class s(object):
    def vrod(self):
        self.name=(input("enter name:"))
        self.stno=int(input("enter stno:"))
        self.score=int(input("enter score:"))

    def dis(self):
        print("enter name:",self.name,"enter stno:",self.stno,"enter score:",self.score)


y=[]
j=0

while j<3:
    st = s()
    st.vrod()
    y.append(st)
    j+=1

for st in y:
    st.dis()
```